# How to create classes for geometric shapes (points, lines, square, triangle, etc.) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, geometry, shapes

We were asked to create geometric shapes via classes. We must create:

1. A Point class.
2. A Line class (line - when two points are connected).
3. A square class.

I created a Point class, with accessible coordinates (2D):

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y
  def initialize
    @x = 10
    @y = 10
  end
  def x=(value)
    @x = value
  end
  def x()
    @x
  end
  def y=(value)
    @y = value
  end
  def y()
    @y
  end
end
```

And, I want to create a new point class:

```
p = Point.new
  p.x = 1
  p.y = 5
  print p # -> #<Point:0x007f9463089cc0>
```

And, as a result, I have some thing like this:

```
#<Point:0x007f9463089cc0>
```

What does this mean?

If I `print p.x, p.y` then I will have a understandable result:

```
print p.x, ", ", p.y # -> 1, 5
```

How can I understand this result on the screen?

Is there any use in a real programming job to create point, lines and geometric shapes?

Comment: Note that `print p` will effectively do `print p.to_s`. Try `print p.inspect`.

Comment: @Raffael Not clear what you mean. If that is the case, it would be infinite recursion.

Comment: Is there a use for this in "real programming"? Of course. Your instructor is teaching you how to create classes and extend/reuse them, which is infinitely useful. Creating specific Point, Line, Square, etc., geometric classes isn't something you have to do though, because code already exists to do those and more. But just because something doesn't appear to make sense in the assignment go with it, because there's a reason for it. See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)" as it might help explain why you need to do the first task in its time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write the setters and getters methods:

```
  def x=(value)
    @x = value
  end
  def x()
    @x
  end
  def y=(value)
    @y = value
  end
  def y()
    @y
  end
```

This is because you can use:

```
attr_accessor :x, :y
```

and `attr_accessor` does that for you.

You might want to allow some flexibility in your constructor. Your `initialize` method allows passing the values for `x` and `y` and will default to 10 if nothing is passed, so you can do this:

```
def initialize(x = 10, y = 10)
  @x = x
  @y = y
end
```

This way, you will get this:

```
p1 = Point.new 
puts p.x # => 10
puts p.y # => 10

p2 = Point.new(15, 20)
puts p.x # => 15
puts p.y # => 20
```

Notice how for `p1` I don't pass any arguments and yet `x` and `y` both get set as expected because we are setting a default value for them in the method definition, here:

```
def initialize(x = 10, y = 10)
```

Regarding your question about why you see this:

```
p = Point.new
p.x = 1
p.y = 5
print p # -> #<Point:0x007f9463089cc0>
```

`Point:0x007fa003885bf8` means that you have an instance of the class `Point`  in your variable `p`. By default Ruby will call the `to_s` method on an object when you try to print it, since in your case you didn't define that method it will go through the inheritance chain to see who defines that method. It turns out that that method is found in the Object class which all Ruby objects implicitly inherit from, and that method's default behaviour is to print the name of the class followed by the instance's ID in memory, in the format:

```
#<ClassName:MemoryID>
```

See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-to_s

If you want to change that then you can override `to_s` to something like this:

```
def to_s
  "Point #{x},#{y}"
end
```

That way you will get:

```
puts Point.new # => "Point 10,10"
```

Comment: You might also show `p3 = Point.new(15)` and note that one cannot set the value of `@y` and have `@x` set to its default.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong.

```
#<Point:0x007f9463089cc0>
```

simply means that it is an instance (the `#<>` part) of class `Point` with an object ID of `0x007f9463089cc0`. An object ID is an identifier for Ruby's interpreter to find each object, very much like a memory address.

Though everything is okay, there is always a way in Ruby that leads to less code. For example:

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def initialize(x = 10, y = 10)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end
end
```

Or even:

```
Point = Struct.new(:x, :y)
```

Comment: But what is the best way to do this kind of work? I understand: the smaller code = is the better way. But what about computer memory, what type of code will take less memory?

Comment: @AndreyDrozdov In this specific case you don't need to consider too much about memory consumption since all the ways of creating class `Point` consumes O(1) memory, far less than loading data into arrays or hashes that consumes O(n) memory, or loading big files.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring `attr_accessor :x, :y`
you actually don't need to define a getter and setter for `x` and `y`,
so your class can be simplified to:

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y
  def initialize
    @x = 10
    @y = 10
  end
end
```

Also you can add a `to_s`  method to Point:

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y
  def initialize
    @x = 10
    @y = 10
  end

  def to_s
     "(#{x}, #{y})"
  end
end
```

so you can use `puts p` and get as ouptut `(10, 10)` when you do:

```
p = Point.new
puts p
(10, 10)
```

I prefer to use `puts` instead of `print` because it insert a new-line character after the output, and it looks more readable.
In `to_s`  I'm using Ruby's string interpolation `"#{}"` to build a nice output for your Point instance.

Answer (score 0):

Methods `print` and `puts` output the result of `to_s`, and `p` outputs the result of `inspect`. Unless you overwrite these methods, by default, a custom class that inherits `Object` returns the form `#<class_name:object_id>` that you got. If you want some other output, overwrite these methods, for example

```
class Point
  def to_s
    "#@x,#@y"
  end
end
...
print p
```